Indistinguishability of $(G_0(x), G_1(x))$ from $(G_0(x), t)$ where $G(x) = G_0(x) \| G_1(x)$ is a PRG
Suppose, $G:\{0,1\}^{\lambda} \rightarrow \{0,1\}^{2\lambda}$ is a length doubling pseudorandom generator (PRG). Such a PRG is used to build PRF $F: \{0,1\}^{\lambda} \rightarrow \{0,1\}^{\lambda}$ using the GGM technique. Let us denote $G(x) = G_0(x) \| G_1(x)$ where $G_b:\{0,1\}^{\lambda} \rightarrow \{0,1\}^{\lambda}$ for both $b \in \{0,1\}$. How do we show that if an efficient adversary $\mathcal{A}$ can distinguish an element $(G_0(x), G_1(x))$ from $(G_0(x), t)$ where $x, t$ are chosen uniformly at random, then there is an (explicit) efficient adversary $\mathcal{B}$ that can be used to break the pseudorandomness property of $G$?

Let $p_0 = Pr_{x}[\mathcal{A}(G_0(x), G_1(x)) = 1]$ and $p_1 = Pr_{x, t} [\mathcal{A}(G_0(x), t) = 1]$. Since $\mathcal{A}$ can distinguish an element $(G_0(x), G_1(x))$ from $(G_0(x), t)$, this means that $|p_0 - p_1|$ is large. Let's also define $p_{0.5} = Pr_{t_0, t_1} [\mathcal{A}(t_0, t_1) = 1]$, i.e, the probability with which $\mathcal{A}$ outputs 1 on input $(t_0, t_1)$ which are truly random strings. Then, $|(p_0 - p_{0.5}) + (p_{0.5} - p_1)|$ is large which means at least one of $|(p_0 - p_{0.5})|$ and $|(p_1 - p_{0.5})|$ is large. Suppose,

$|p_0 - p_{0.5}|$ is large. This implies that $\mathcal{A}$ that can distinguish an element $(G_0(x), G_1(x))$ from $(t_0, t_1)$ where $x, t_0, t_1$ are chosen uniformly at random. In other words, $\mathcal{B}$ is exactly $\mathcal{A}$.
$|(p_1 - p_{0.5})|$ is large. Then, $\mathcal{B}$ works as follows. On receiving $(z_0, z_1)$ from the PRG challenger, it randomly generate $t$ and returns $\mathcal{A}(z_0, t)$. Observe that if $(z_0, z_1) = (G_0(x), G_1(x))$, then $(z_0, t) = (G_0(x), t)$ and $\mathcal{B}$ would output 1 with probability $p_1$. Otherwise, if $(z_0, z_1) = (t_0, t_1)$, then $(z_0, t) = (t_0, t)$ which has the same distribution as $(t_0, t_1)$ and $\mathcal{B}$ would output 1 with probability $p_{0.5}$.

